# What is the difference between GitHub actions/checkout@v3 and v2?

Tags: github-actions

When using [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions), what is the difference between `actions/checkout@v2` and `actions/checkout@v3`?  Is there any reason to use v2 over v3?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The node runtime version upgrade is what motivated them to make a new major version release. That can be seen in the diff here: https://github.com/actions/checkout/compare/v2.4.2...v3.0.2#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R17-R18

Comment: thanks, and good find! You are correct **(node12 --> node16)**.  It looks like there is also a new option default for "set-safe-directory" which is not listed in the changes. 

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions.